# When the חזן has finished and a mourner is saying קדיש, at what point is it correct for the חזן to leave the עמוד?

Tags: tefilla, chazzan-prayer-leader, kaddish, middos-character-traits

When the חזן has finished the prayers and a mourner is saying קדיש, at what point is it correct for him to remove his טלית (if he is wearing one) and leave the עמוד?

On the one hand it seems respectful to stay until the mourner has finished - on the other it seems that the חזן is waiting to get the praise for his prayers.

Comment: *Personal view -  no sources* - Since the Hazan should be concentrating on the responses (esp Yhei Shmei Rabba.....) it strikes me that he should not be engaged in taking off hos tallit, switching the amud light off etc. until after the end of Kaddish. Maybe he should turn aside and face the mourner so as to transfer the focus of attention to him.

Answer (score 7):

I have no source other than my teachers(' Mesorah?), but I was taught, and I believe, that it is proper for the חזן to wait until after the completion of the קדיש.

It seems to me that, rather than waiting for praise, he is preventing distraction, and his presence and staid stance at the עמוד help to maintain the decorum through the last words of the קדיש.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the mourner is temporarily the Shaliach Tzibbur while saying Kaddish -- in a sense, he is taking over for the Chazzan -- and the *t'filah* is not complete until Kaddish is said.  Hence, the Chazzan should stand where he was and answer Kaddish just like the rest of the *tzibbur* -- just as it is not ideal for any member of the *tzibbur* to remove his *talis* and/or walk away from the davening before that davening is complete, the Chazzan should not do so, especially as (despite the concept of "mima'amakim" implying he should be below the geographic/physical level of the *tzibbur*) he is usually the most visible member of the *tzibbur*.